# What to do if we don't get m+n-1 basic variables in stepping stone method?

Tags: operations-research

In stepping stone method (for transportation model), it is one of the requirements that number of basic variables must be m+n-1, where m and n are no of rows and columns respectively.My question is: How to proceed if we do not get m+n-1 basic variables?

Comment: Can you give a little bit more context? I think I know what you're talking about but I want to be sure.

Comment: Transportation model can be solved by simplex method but due to its special structure we have a more efficient method for solving it that's "stepping stone method".This method like simplex method also requires intial solution which we find by "north-west corner method".When we have initial solution we have basics variables which must be m+n-1 to apply stepping stone method.What to do if basics variables are less than that?